# bootstrap tagsinput allowing duplicates even when set to false

Tags: jquery, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-tags-input

tags-input is allowing duplicates wen I set a value in html

```
<input type="text" value="XYZ" class="tagsResult tagIn form-control" data-role="tagsinput sometext" data-color="success">
```

Then when I try to add same tag dynamically it is getting added.

```
$(".tagsResult").tagsinput('add', 'XYZ');
    $(".tagsResult").tagsinput('refresh');
```

Again when I manually type in the same "XYZ" it accepts again, but if I do it repeatedly beside newly typed, it works properly i.e it wont allow, but in above two cases it is allowing duplicate when it should not.

Anyone have faced similar issue? Do let me know how can this be fixed.

Comment: did you set **allowDuplicates** to false?

Comment: Yes I did. I mentioned in title about it :)

Comment: That's sounds strange. Because I cannot reproduce the problem, may you add more info:  Html fragment, js libs.... Thanks